# Is there anything like JSON.stringify in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I find myself needing to `JSON.stringify(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someJavaBean));` server side in Java as I make an HttpClient call to another service in our infrastructure.  Does Jackson have any such function?  Is there an easy way to do this without adding another dependency to my project?

If it matters, we are Jackson 2.3.2.

What I need to do is convert some JSON like

```
{ "first_name" : "Robert", "last_name" : "Kuhar" }
```

Into a Javascript String like

```
"{ \"first_name\" : \"Robert\", \"last_name\" : \"Kuhar\" }"
```

Its not as simple as Replace all the quotes with \", is it?  Like what happens if there are quotes embedded in the values?  Or some of the values are single quote delimited?  It seems like there should be a library call to do this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someObject);
String encodedASecondTime = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(json);
```

As simple as that. Not sure why you would want that, though, since a JSON value is a valid object literal already. You can do

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someObject);
```

and then generate javascript like

```
"var obj = " + json + ";"
```

Comment: "Not sure why you would want to"  Sigh.  I don't want to.  I am dealing with a JSON Message Format that is acting as an "envelope", but not a very flexible on.  The message format itself is JSON, but I have to stuff my payload into a single field with the message JSON as a String.  The only legitimate value of that string, you may ask?  "Stringified" JSON.  Yuk.  I think your solution works, I'm just testing it out.

Comment: If input contains untrusted data, then it's important to add `.replace("</", "<\\/">)` after `writeValueAsString(...)` to secure against XSS attacks escaping from (e.g. 'var obj' is living in) `<script>...</script>` context. However, this is not required for API responses and most other JSON contexts.